# ComboBox SelectedIndexChanged event: how to get the previously selected index?

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-3.5

I have a user control which has a ComboBox and a SelectedIndexChanged event handler.  In the event handler, I need to be able to tell what was the previously selected index... can anyone point me in the right direction?

```
private void cboTargetMode_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // need to get the previously selected index and do some handling here...
    // ... some handler code here ...


    switch (cboTargetMode.SelectedIndex)
    {
        case 1:  // ..... some code here...
            break;
        case 2:  // ..... some code here...
            break;
        case 3:  // ..... some code here...
            break;
        default: // ..... some code here...
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

There is nothing built in, you will need to listen for this event and keep track in an instance variable.

Use -1 as an uninitialized "last index", so on first pass you set it but don't use it.  Subsequent passes you use it and set it.

You could always do this using a derived ComboBox class of your own and override `OnSelectedIndexChanged` and expose a `PreviousSelectedIndex` property.  This way, it wouldn't be tightly coupled to the form.  Alternatively, as you can do this using events, its also eligible for implementation as an [extender provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171836.aspx).

Comment: Shouldn't it rather be "instance variable" instead of "class variable" ?

Comment: @FrankSchmitt Chasing a badge dredging up a near 8 year old post? ;-) But yes you are correct, I've amended my answer.

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth Thanks. And no, I'm (currently) not on a badge hunt :-)

Answer (score 3):

I guess you will have to store the current (that will become the previous later on) into a  variable so that it is used like a cache or something like so.

```
private void cboTargetMode_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    // need to get the previously selected index and do some handling here...
    // ... some handler code here ...

    // Assuming that the variable PreviousSelectedIndex is declared in the class with value -1.
    if (PreviousSelectedIndex < 0)
        PreviousSelectedIndex = cbo.TargetMode.SelectedIndex;
    else
        // Do some handling here...

    switch (cboTargetMode.SelectedIndex) {
        case 1:  // ..... some code here...
            break;
        case 2:  // ..... some code here...
            break;
        case 3:  // ..... some code here...
            break;
        default: // ..... some code here...
            break;
    }
}
```

Is this something you have already thought of?

Otherwise, perhaps working with the [`Control.Validating`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/system.windows.forms.control.validating(v=VS.80).aspx) event? I just can't say whether this event occurs before or after the `SelectedIndexChanged` event. =(

Answer (score 0):

how about the comboBox_SelectionChangeCommitted event? this is called after the selection is made, the menu is collapsed but the item is not compleetly changed. So just read comboBox.SelectedText or comboBox.SelectedValue and even comboBox.SelectedIndex

```
private void comboBox1_SelectionChangeCommitted(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int prevIndex = comboBox1.SelectedIndex;
}
```

Comment: @Zekeriya, this was from 6 years ago, but I resolved the problem by two-way binding the `SelectedItem` and managing the previous selection in the `setter` of the binded property on the view model. And truth be told, this turned out to be the better way, since it was easier to do, and was control-agnostic -- which meant that I didn't need to write some handler code for every different control that I would bind the list to.

Comment: Ok I needed a solutiion for this problem last month but the accepted awnser did not work for me. In some kind of way your current response also did not work but I will check it later on... Thanks for the response anyway :)

Comment: The current MVVM philosophy that we are using @ my shop is to avoid converters, avoid behaviors (unless absolutely necessary) and try to get the viewmodel to do more work - i.e. make *it* provide the SelectedItem, etc.

Answer (score 0):

This one to get the current selected index ,I just need it and I couldn't find anywhere ,so I hope it helps

```
 private void lsbx_layers_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int i = lsbx_layers.SelectedIndices[0];//selected index
            MessageBox.Show("Selected item at index : " + i);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue to this in which I set all my combo boxes to "autocomplete" using

```
ComboBox.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend;
ComboBox.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.ListItems;
```

I looped through and set all their lostFocus Events:

```
foreach(Control control in this.Controls)
{
    if(control is ComboBox)
   {
        ((ComboBox)control).LostFocus += ComboBox_LostFocus;
   }
}
```

and had a dictionary object to hold old values

```
public Dictionary<string, int> comboBoxOldValues = new Dictionary<string, int>();
```

then finally ensure the value exists or set to old index, then save to the dictionary

```
private void ComboBox_LostFocus(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ComboBox comboBox = (ComboBox)sender;

    if (comboBox.DataSource is List<YourDataType>)
    {
        if (((List<YourDataType>)comboBox.DataSource).Count(x => x.YourValueMember == (YourValueMemberType)comboBox.SelectedValue) == 0)
        {
            if (comboBoxOldValues.Keys.Count(x => x == comboBox.Name) > 0)
            {
                comboBox.SelectedIndex = comboBoxOldValues[comboBox.Name];
            }
            else
                comboBox.SelectedIndex = -1;
        }
    }            

    if (comboBoxOldValues.Keys.Count(x => x == comboBox.Name) > 0)
    {
        comboBoxOldValues[comboBox.Name] = comboBox.SelectedIndex;
    }
    else
        comboBoxOldValues.Add(comboBox.Name,  comboBox.SelectedIndex);

    if (comboBox.SelectedIndex == -1)
        comboBox.Text = string.Empty;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can grab & store the old value in the `DropDown` event. Then revert to that old value in the `SelectionChangeCommitted` event (if warranted).