# Get selected Object from Combobox

Tags: c#, object, combobox

I have this `Combobox` filled with objects
And Upon selecting a certain object from the `combobox` I would like to show Text in a `Textbox`, but for some reason I can't get my selection through.

This is what is in my `combobox`:

```
 private void showBirds()
    {
        cboBirds.Items.Clear();
        foreach (Bird b in Bird.ReadBirdCSV(txtFile.Text))
        {
            cboBirds.Items.Add(b);
        }
    }
```

It basically shows the names of birds from the Objects Bird.

```
 private void cboBirds_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {

//WHAT DO I WRITE HERE TO GET txbGender TO SHOW THE GENDER?

        foreach (Bird b in cboBirds.Items)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(b.Gender +" - " + b.Name +" - " + b.Risk + " - " +b.Reference);
        }
//^This shows all info on every bird.

    }
```

I'm sure it's really simple, I just can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: I don't understand the `Console.WriteLine(...` part, if you have a TextBox you have to set `Text` properties of it. Maybe i missing something?

Comment: You are completely right, I just put it there to point out that there are in fact objects in my cbo, not just strings

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3237885/combobox-selectedindexchanged-event-how-to-get-the-previously-selected-index

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [ComboBox.SelectedIndexChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.selectedindexchanged.aspx) event

```
private void ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
     if(ComboBox1.SelectedItem==null) return;
     var b= (Bird) ComboBox1.SelectedItem;
     if(b!=null)
         Console.WriteLine(b.Gender +" - " + b.Name +" - " + b.Risk + " - " +b.Reference);
}
```

Comment: Just the solution what was looking for

Comment: cannot cast DataRowView to Author. any solution ? thanks